# jQuery radio button newbie question

Tags: jquery, input

I have a table of radio buttons that have an ID value that contains an item number

```
<input type="radio" id="rb169">
<input type="radio" id="rb170">
<input type="radio" id="rb171">
```

How can I use jQuery to iterate through all the radio buttons that start with "rb" to determine which # number was selected?

I have something like:

```
return_type = $("input:radio["@name=rb*"]:checked").val();
if (return_type == undefined) {
    alert("you did not select a radio button");
}
```

but this doesn't work the way I selected.  Is this right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$('input:radio[name^=rb]:checked').val()` should do it. You don't need the `@` anymore, nor the extra quotes.

Answer (score 0):

```
return_type = $("input:radio["@name^=rb"]:checked").val();
```

That should work. Starts with is ^=

EDIT: I noticed that your code is wrong in other places as well. I was too narrow in what I was looking at. Here is an update:

```
return_type = $("input:radio[name^='rb']:checked").val();
```